# Explicitly triggering validation in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, validation, ef-code-first, fluent, explicit

I am using Entity Framework 6 with Unit of Work Repository pattern. I am having all the entities mapped with the database using the fluent API. and also the validation conditions which needs to be satisfied.

Now i was searching a way to explicitly call validation for each entity and i found a blog post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx (see "Explicitly triggering validation" ) section on the page.

I have tried to call Context.GetValidationErrors() but it not validating any of the rules that are defined using fluent api.

So if some one have any idea on this please feel free to answer this :)

Many Thanks.

```
 public AM_AssetLayoutsConfiguration(string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".AM_AssetLayouts");
        HasKey(x => x.ID);

        Property(x => x.ID).HasColumnName("ID").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(x => x.IncludePCFields).HasColumnName("IncludePCFields").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.DisplayOrder).HasColumnName("DisplayOrder").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.Active).HasColumnName("Active").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.CreatedByID).HasColumnName("CreatedByID").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate").IsRequired();
        Property(x => x.ModifiedByID).HasColumnName("ModifiedByID").IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.ModifiedDate).HasColumnName("ModifiedDate").IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.DeletedByID).HasColumnName("DeletedByID").IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.DeletedDate).HasColumnName("DeletedDate").IsOptional();
        Property(x => x.Deleted).HasColumnName("Deleted").IsRequired();

        InitializePartial();
```

Here is my fluent API mapping.

```
foreach (var validationResults in dbContext.GetValidationErrors()) 
{ 
    foreach (var error in validationResults.ValidationErrors) 
    { 
        Debug.WriteLine( 
                          "Entity Property: {0}, Error {1}", 
                          error.PropertyName, 
                          error.ErrorMessage); 
    } 
}
```

Here is the code that calls the validate method according to blog post.

Update for attaching the entity to db context :

```
repository.EntityDbSet.Add(entity);

                DbEntityValidationResult validationResult = repository.DbContext.Entry<TEntity>(entity).GetValidationResult();

                if (validationResult.IsValid == false)
                {
                    entityValidationResults.IsValid = false;

                    foreach (DbValidationError validationError in validationResult.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        entityValidationResults.ValidationErrors.Add(new EntityValidationError() { PropertyName = validationError.PropertyName, ErrorMessage = validationError.ErrorMessage });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @colin I have added the fluent Api configuration. Please take a look at that

Comment: Where is the code that proves Context.GetValidationErrors() is not validating any of the rules that are defined using fluent api?

Comment: @colin thanks for taking interest. I have edited the question.

Comment: And have you attached an invalid model to the context?

Comment: GetValidationErrors() only validates added and modified entities. From your post is not clear to me if you have added the entities you expect to be validated to the context. DbContext also contains a protected virtual ValidateEntity method you could use to validate a single entity.

Comment: @pawel i am trying to call validation for added and modified entities. I have already added the entity to the current context and then if i try to validate it nothing is validated. I have added the code sample for that. I am not sure what you mean by " From your post is not clear to me if you have added the entities you expect to be validated to the context". if you have the required steps for enabling this validation please let me know

Comment: See this other answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710969/ef-call-validate-on-entity-without-dbcontext